# Nest ScrollView

Tags: android, webview

there are two webviews in scrollview.

```
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
<WebView></WebView>
<WebView></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want to make two webviews looks like one webpage. currently, my solution is make webview's height equal to webview's contentHeight. and disable scrollability of webview. but for very big html. it's not a good solution. webview has to render the whole html. I want to use nestedscrollview. make two webviews' height equals to nestedscrollview's height. but I dont known how to deal the events.

Comment: but why you want to use 2 webviews ?

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan because there are two webpages from different websites

Comment: @WhatisThat try my below answer

Comment: @WhatisThat did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @AkhileshPatil thanks. but it seems that android:layout_height="wrap_content" will make the webview as heigh as its content. also I cannot scroll to the second webview. /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Comment: @WhatisThat at my end,  I'm able to scroll on both webviews

Answer (score 2):

Try this to make two WebView looks like one webpage.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String url = "http://www.yahoo.com";
    String url1 = "http://www.google.com";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Activity one");

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());
        webview.loadUrl(url);

        WebView webview2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        webview2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());
        webview2.loadUrl(url1);

    }
}
```

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

WebView client

```
class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```